# How to close connection of a WCF client instantiated via interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a WCF client that has been instantiated via its interface on my MVC 4 project  controller like this:

```
private readonly ILMS_Service lms_client;

public ProductsController(ILMS_Service client)
{
    lms_client = client;
}

public ProductsController()
{
    lms_client = new LMS_ServiceClient();
}
```

I can access the operation contracts from the client, but what I noticed on this implementation is that there's no `.Open()` and `.Close()` methods as I would normally access with `LMS_Client lms_client = new LMS_ServiceClient();`. I cannot use this conventional way initializing the WCF client since I need to be able to pass mock WCF client from my unit tests. With this, I have to initialize the WCF client via it's interface and have to make a constructor to pass the mock service whenever I test.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924045/disposing-of-a-wcf-client-instantiated-via-an-interface), however it doesn't tell me anything where to implement the `Dispose()` method (e.g. to the Controller or on the `.svc` file of the WCF project?). And I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573925/8331324) doesn't seem to have unit testing in mind. It seems to implement the interface for every call of the methods on the WCF; in which, it is not mockable. In addition, I have also found [this blog](https://johan.driessen.se/posts/do-not-forget-to-close-your-wcf-serviceclients/) which is the closest to my scenario, but is this a good way of closing the connection via a destructor? Where do you implement it? On the Controller calling the method or the on the `.svc` file of the WCF project?

It would be great if someone could enlighten me or show me a good way of opening/closing WCF client connection with this implementation through an example. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to close the connection of the WCF service if you are using it via interface. You can use the `Dispose` method on the class and cast your WCF service interface to the actual implementation.

```
private readonly ILMS_Service lms_client;

public ProductsController(ILMS_Service client)
{
    lms_client = client;
}

public ProductsController()
{
    lms_client = new LMS_ServiceClient();
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) {
        var clientObject = lms_client as LMS_ServiceClient;
        if (clientObject != null && clientObject.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
            clientObject.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When closing the WCF connection, I suggest you follow [@Lan Huang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73957237/8331324) or [@Rico Sutter's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27924123/8331324), the same can be found on [@Rico Sutter's blog](https://blog.rsuter.com/correctly-handle-wcf-clients-life-cycle-simple-way/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use close and abort to release wcf client resources as suggested by Microsoft documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources

```
try
{
    ...
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

The first link you provided is basically creating a partial class for the WCF client and then inheriting the Dispose method.
For details, you can check the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose